# Android Plugin for Gradle 2.2.2 and Gradle version 2.14.1 together failed to download android support v4

Tags: android

Android application build fails with Android Plugin for Gradle 2.2.2 and Gradle version 2.14.1.
But build successful with Android Plugin for Gradle 1.2.3 and Gradle version 2.3

**Expected Behavior:**

Android application should successfully build in command line with Android Plugin for Gradle 2.2.2 and Gradle version 2.14.1

**Current Behavior:**

Android application build fails with Android Plugin for Gradle 2.2.2 and Gradle version 2.14.1. Because it fails to find a symbol in the com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.1.
Also build fails in the Android Studio with the same reason.

**Context:**

I had to updated the Android Studio to 2.2.2(Latest) and this must use at least Android Plugin for Gradle 2.2.2. Therefore I had to update gradle as well. (Tried both gradle 2.14.1 and gradle 3.2) But build fails with the same reason.

Steps to Reproduce

Have the following settings in the application `gradle.build` file

```
repositories {
  jcenter()
}

dependencies {
  classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'
}
```

Also

```
dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.1'
}
```

Android SDK is uptodate
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BRvRu.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ffQ0H.png)

And run the gradle build.
Build fails and out put's following errors

```
error: cannot find symbol
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
^
error: cannot find symbol
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
```

Answer (score 1):

When you try to update Gradle by yourself sometimes does not work, the best way y let android studio do it.

Step 1:
Close Your project

Step 2:
Reopen your project.

Step 3:
Click on update button [image]

Step 4:
Wait update

Thats all!

Comment: I have updated gradle properly. That's not the problem. when I have updated gradle to 2.14.1 and android plugin for gradle in the gradle.build file to 2.2.2, build fails saying it can't find the 'error: cannot find symbol import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment; ^ error: cannot find symbol import'

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to Invalidate Caches of Android Studio after upgrade gradle?

To do that you have to go:

File -> Invalidate caches / restart... -> Invalidate and Restart

[image]

Comment: Yep did doesn't work. I can't even get this working command line.